# How can i fix a PHP Warning: Attempt to read property "slug" on bool caused by WP search?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, bigcommerce, wpengine

Our website search function suddenly quit working this morning and no longer reads big commerce product's SKUs when showing search results.

I spent the last couple of hours working with the WP engine to restore our theme's header file as it had been causing issues. That has been fixed; however, I now get this error log:

> PHP Warning: "Attempt to read property "slug" on bool in /nas/content/live/sonictools/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/templates/admin/query-builder.php on lines 67 & 68."

The search results still don't show the product SKUs. so like, if I search an SKU it returns no results. Anyway, here is the snippet the error log is showing has a problem:

```
    data-value="<?php echo intval( $sale->term_id ); ?>"
    data-slug="<?php echo esc_attr( $sale->slug ); ?>"
```

The entire file is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Query Builder sidebar for the Admin UI Dialog Template.
 *
 * @package BigCommerce Admin
 *
 * @var \WP_Term|false $featured
 * @var \WP_Term|false $sale
 * @var array          $brands
 * @var array          $categories
 * @var array          $channels
 */

use BigCommerce\Import\Import_Type;
use BigCommerce\Taxonomies\Brand\Brand;
use BigCommerce\Taxonomies\Channel\Channel;
use BigCommerce\Taxonomies\Flag\Flag;
use BigCommerce\Taxonomies\Product_Category\Product_Category;

?>

<aside class="bc-shortcode-ui__selectors" role="complementary">
    <figure
            class="bc-shortcode-ui__logo"
            aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'BigCommerce Product Query Builder', 'bigcommerce' ); ?>"
    ></figure>

    <?php if ( count( $channels ) > 1 ) {
        printf( '<label for="bcqb-channels" class="bc-shortcode-ui__channel-select">%s <select name="%s" id="bcqb-channels" data-js="bcqb-channels">', esc_html( __( 'Select a Channel', 'bigcommerce' ) ), Channel::NAME );
        foreach ( $channels as $channel ) {
            printf( '<option value="%d" %s data-primary="%s">%s</option>', $channel['id'], selected( $channel['primary'], true, false ), $channel['primary'], esc_html( $channel['name'] ) );
        }
        echo '</select></label>';
    } ?>

    <ul class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-list" data-js="bcqb-list">
        <?php if ( Import_Type::is_traditional_import() ) : ?>
            <li class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-list-item">
                <a
                    href="#"
                    class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-anchor"
                    data-key="recent"
                    data-value="1"
                    data-slug="<?php esc_html_e( 'recent', 'bigcommerce' ); ?>"
                    data-depth="0"
                ><?php esc_html_e( 'Recent', 'bigcommerce' ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( $featured ) { ?>
            <li class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-list-item">
                <a
                    href="#"
                    class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-anchor"
                    data-key="<?php echo esc_attr( Flag::NAME ); ?>"
                    data-value="<?php echo intval( $featured->term_id ); ?>"
                    data-slug="<?php echo esc_attr( $featured->slug ); ?>"
                    data-depth="0"
                ><?php esc_html_e( 'Featured', 'bigcommerce' ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ( $sale ) { ?>
            <li class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-list-item">
                <a
                    href="#"
                    class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-anchor"
                    data-key="<?php echo esc_attr( Flag::NAME ); ?>"
                    data-value="<?php echo intval( $sale->term_id ); ?>"
                    data-slug="<?php echo esc_attr( $sale->slug ); ?>"
                    data-depth="0"
                ><?php esc_html_e( 'On Sale', 'bigcommerce' ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ( $brands ) { ?>
            <li class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-list-item" data-js="bcqb-parent-list-item">
                <button type="button" class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-toggle" data-js="bcqb-has-child-list">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Brands', 'bigcommerce' ); ?> <i class="bc-icon icon-bc-arrow-toggle"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-child-list">
                    <?php foreach ( $brands as $term ) { ?>
                        <li class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-list-item">
                            <a
                                href="#"
                                class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-anchor"
                                data-key="<?php echo esc_attr( Brand::NAME ); ?>"
                                data-value="<?php echo intval( $term['id'] ); ?>"
                                data-slug="<?php echo esc_attr( $term['slug'] ); ?>"
                                data-depth="<?php echo esc_attr( $term['depth'] ); ?>"
                            ><?php echo esc_html( $term['name'] ); ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ( $categories ) { ?>
            <li class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-list-item" data-js="bcqb-parent-list-item">
                <button type="button" class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-toggle" data-js="bcqb-has-child-list">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Categories', 'bigcommerce' ); ?> <i class="bc-icon icon-bc-arrow-toggle"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-child-list">
                    <?php foreach ( $categories as $term ) { ?>
                        <li class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-list-item">
                            <a
                                href="#"
                                class="bc-shortcode-ui__query-builder-anchor"
                                data-key="<?php echo esc_attr( Product_Category::NAME ); ?>"
                                data-value="<?php echo intval( $term['id'] ); ?>"
                                data-slug="<?php echo esc_attr( $term['slug'] ); ?>"
                                data-depth="<?php echo esc_attr( $term['depth'] ); ?>"
                            ><?php echo esc_html( $term['name'] ); ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

I have tried restoring the header.php. I have tried talking with WP Engine support. They uplaoded the restore to my database. but they are unable to help me here. I dont know what could be causing this issue. Please any help

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $sale );` inside that `if ( $sale ) {` condition and see what that returns.

Comment: Could you show me what that would look like specifically? Ill run this on the staging environment and get back to you asap! I appreciate your help too. This is such an urgent issue.

Comment: Something like `<?php if ( $sale ) { var_dump( $sale );  ?>` should do.